# Why Python ctypes can not FreeLibrary?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ctypes, dllexport

```
>>>h=cdll.LoadLibrary('dll.dll')
>>>h.hello()       # messageBox
1
>>>windll.kernel32.FreeLibrary(h._handle)
1
>>>h.hello()      #and still have messageBox,Why....
1
```

and this is the dll source

```
#include <windows.h>
#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HANDLE hModule, DWORD  fdwReason,LPVOID lpReserved)   {}

DLL_EXPORT void hello (void)
{
    MessageBox (0, "Hello World!", "From DLL", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  The same sequence crashes for me on the second call to `hello`.  Using Python 2.7 32-bit.  What happens when you call `FreeLibrary` twice?  It should return 0 if the library was already unloaded.

Comment: As a side note, libraries are reference counted on Windows, which means a library is only freed (unloaded from memory) once its reference reaches 0. So if you have a dangling reference on a module, it wont be freed automatically even if you call `FreeLibrary`.

Comment: Not able to reproduce. On 32bit the 2nd call raises `WindowsError` (*Access Violation*), while on 64bit, `kernel32.FreeLibrary` fails with `exceptions.OverflowError` (when trying to convert the handle value to `int`).